# Is there a way to reload data using file manager?

Tags: swift, file-manager

I am setting up a view controller where the user picks a custom background image to be displayed on the previous view controller instead of the default background.

- The user selects a photo from their photo library which is saved using fileManager.
- the correct new background image is then displayed in the tableViewCell
- After exiting the view controller. The new selected background gets displayed.

The current problem I am having is that after dismissing the view controller the background does not change to the new one *IF* the user is changing from one new background to another new one.

- If they are changing from the default background to the new one it changes fine. If I change from one new background to another to background and close the app. The right one will be displayed upon opening.
- Also if i use the swipe function to delete the image stored at thefilePath the default background is displayed fine upon dismissing.

The problem only occurs going from one new background to another. The problem also occurs when going back into the 2nd view controller to change the background. The cell displays the old "new background image" again. even though it did update to the correct new one upon its original selection.

**I feel as if the fileManager loads the data(images) upon launch or upon originally creating it (first time background is changed), and even though this data is being over written. its does not load it again until the app is closed and relaunched.**

The viewDidLoad function is called when dismissing the second view controller using a protocol to reload the view controller so the new background is displayed.

I have print statements showing the filePaths and the new background image that replaced the other old "new background image" and the background image filePath being called upon viewDidLoad are exact matches.

However the old "new background image" is still displayed.

```
//Row selected
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Image to change picked in row \(indexPath.row)")
    lastSelectedIndex = indexPath
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// places selected image in image array and reloads table data so image is displaced in cell - also calls save photo
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let photo = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {

        //removeCustomPicture(imagePath: customImagesArray[lastSelectedIndex!.row].filePath, row: lastSelectedIndex!.row)


        customImagesArray[lastSelectedIndex!.row].image = photo
        customImagesArray[lastSelectedIndex!.row].filePath = saveImage(imageName: "\(customImageLabelArray[lastSelectedIndex!.row]).png", row: lastSelectedIndex!.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else {
        print("Error retrieving image")
    }
}

//save photo
func saveImage(imageName: String, row: Int) -> String{

    print("save image called")
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    //get the image path
    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)

    print("save image function: \(imagePath)")
    //get the image we took from photo library
    let image = customImagesArray[row].image

    //get the PNG data for this image
    let data = image.pngData()

    //store it in the document directory
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    return imagePath
}


//load image
func getImage(imageName: String, row: Int) -> String {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(imageName).png")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath){
        customImagesArray[row].image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: imagePath)
        print("get image called")
    } else {
        print("Panic! No Image!")
    }
    return imagePath
}
```

Comment: Are you sure lastSelectedIndex is still valid?  Also, blindly using lastSelectedIndex by calling `lastSelectedIndex!` can be a possible source of bugs. You can make is safe by doing `guard let index = lastSelectedIndex` or `if let index = lastSelectedIndex` just to be safe.

Comment: I changed my code to incorporate what you said above, however there is no changes. The code still does not work. 

When running the app on my simulator. I put in breakpoints and open the filePath and can see the image being changed to the new background that is stored. Before the first view controller calls the filePath to get the image. 

However the first view controller still displays the old one. until I close the app and re open it. Then it displays the correct background.